# Comparing objects of NSArray1 to NSArray2

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Here is what i need it to do.

NSArray has 10 objects

NSArray2 has the same 10 objects but in different indexes.

**I need to compare if NSArray1 index:5 matches NSArray2 index:5 if not tell me if the object has moved up or down in the NSArray2, same for every other object inside that array.**

The objects have the following properties: id and name.

Any suggestion on how i can accomplish this?

Comment: Is this Homework? Are you comparing them by name or id?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of question that one would get in a job interview.

Comment: None it's actually for my own app, i need this :p

Answer (score 1):

If you have RAM to spare you could build a map from the object's id to its index in array 1, then scan array 2 and compare, like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < array1.count; j++) {
    id object = array1[j];
    map[object.id] = @(j);
}
for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < array2.count; j++) {
    id object = array2[j];
    id identifier = object.id;
    NSUInteger array1Index = [map[identifier] unsignedIntegerValue];
    // Compare array1Index to j here.
}
```

That'll let you compare with a running time that grows like the number of objects in the arrays, but note that you have to spend some extra RAM to make that `map`.  You could compare with only constant RAM costs if you're willing to spend more time:

```
for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < array1.count; j++) {
    id object = array1[j];
    NSUInteger k = [array2 indexOfObject:object];
    // Compare j and k, note that k could be NSNotFound.
}
```

And that should have a running time that grows like the product of the array counts.